# Filter/subset of data frames

Tags: r

I have this dataset that I call:crime and I want to sort/filter only let's say Rape from the crime category column and show all occurrences. But the closest I get is that it shows True but not showing the actual word "Rape". What am I doing wrong? I have tried to use subset and/or filter but to no avail. It works in Pandas (Jypyter notebook) with slightly different code. This is my line in RStudio. Thanks for any ideas in advance.

Shows True/False: 
View(crime["UCR.CRIME.CATEGORY"]=="RAPE")

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it's a factor or a character before you use this command.

`rset = subset(data, crime == 'Rape')`

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply. The data frame is called crime and the column is ucr.crime.category. I tested to replace with the dataset crime etc. So the line should look something like this: rset=subset(crime,ucr.crime.category=="Rape") but the list turns up empty.

Comment: Both the variable and the value are case sensitive.

Comment: Great! That did it. Thank you so much :-)